# Prawn Rails, generate table with some content not bound by table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn

I am trying to build a fairly complex pdf using Prawn in Rails.

The document I am trying to generate is a form of script split into four columns. The script is comprised of a collection of 'snippets', which are iterated through and populate the third column. If a snippet has special properties it can also populate any one of the other three columns as well. This is all achieved very easily using tables. However, I then need to be able to draw an arrow of some description (using prawn graphics) at certain points spanning between the table columns (please see attached image).

[image: demo table]

How is this achieved since content is bound by table cells? Is there a way to later draw these lines using cursor points or some other method?

Please ask for further for clarification if I'm not making any sense.

Thanks

Comment: Imo, it is simpler to create HTML with styles and convert it to PDF with wkhtmltopdf. [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf).
Sorry if changing the gem is not suitable for you.

Comment: @user1201917 thanks, but I'm not sure how wicked_pdf handles the overflow of text like prawn? I have no way of knowing how long a the text area might be.